# How to use Custom font for @react-pdf/renderer

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I'm trying to use my custom font for creating a pdf file using @react-pdf/renderer.

Here is my code:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  text: {
    fontFamily: "Nunito",
  },
});

const MainPage = () => {
  Font.register({
    family: "Nunito",
    src: "./ttf/Nunito-Regular.ttf",
  });

  return (
    <Document>
      <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Reserve Number: </Text>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};
```

and i'm getting this error:

```
index.js:1 Error: Unknown font format
    at Object.push../node_modules/@react-pdf/fontkit/lib/fontkit.browser.es.js.fontkit.create (fontkit.browser.es.js:49)
    at FontSource._callee2$ (font.js:73)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:294)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:119)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
```

and i tried every way of addressing the font, but nothing worked.

any help or would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: [I have answer it in this link. Click to see it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70577891/15132274)

Comment: [I have answer it in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70126411/how-to-add-custom-font-in-react-pdf-pdf/70577891#70577891). The seconde method is the recommended

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this issue as well. I was able to resolve it by importing the font file as a variable then using that as the src value.

```
import font from "./font.ttf"

Font.register({
  family: "FamilyName",
  format: "truetype",
  src: font 
});


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    fontFamily: "FamilyName",
  },
 });
```

this worked for me.

Comment: for  anyone looking for font adding issue on pdfme , I did the same and it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue,fortunately I was using Google fonts and I solved it by using curl on font import url like so:

`curl 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo&display=swap'`

And copying the ttf url from the response which shows as such

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cairo';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/cairo/v20/SLXVc1nY6HkvangtZmpcWmhzfH5lWWgsQQ.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```